# In spring-boot 2.6.2 Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.groovy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, spring-boot-2.6.0

I migrated my spring boot app for spring-boot 2.5.6 to spring-boot 2.6.2, but since then the start up tells

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from classpath:logback-spring.groovyCaused by: ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException:

Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException:Unexpected filename extension of file [file:/xyz/out/production/resources/logback-spring.groovy]. Should be either .groovy or .xml

Can someone help if you have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: I'm facing the same problem in a Grails 5.1.3 application (which uses 2.6.2 underneath).
Have you found any solution?

Comment: we used 2.6.4, it worked

Comment: In my case I add the org.codehaus.janino:janino dependency follow the link
https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#aot-build-setup-configuration
It worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

Logback 1.2.9 dropped the support for Groovy.

You can either migrate your `logback.groovy` to `logback.xml` or downgrade the logback version to 1.2.7 (`logback.version=1.2.7`) and see if they’ll come around and support Groovy again ([which they might](https://jira.qos.ch/projects/LOGBACK/issues/LOGBACK-1606)).