# ContextInitializer in logback-classic version 1.2.9 does not support Groovy config file

Tags: spring-boot, groovy

Updated to spring-boot-starter-parent 2.6.2 and my application can not start due to following error

`Unexpected filename extension of file [file:logback.groovy]. Should be either .groovy or .xml`. Looked at source code of mentioned class and found following:

```
        final String urlString = url.toString();
        if (urlString.endsWith("xml")) {
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
            configurator.doConfigure(url);
        } else {
            throw new LogbackException("Unexpected filename extension of file [" + url.toString() + "]. Should be either .groovy or .xml");
        }
```

So looks like in the latest version they just removed groovy support? Is there any work around besides just moving back to excel configuration? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no workaround. Groovy support was removed in 1.2.9 for security reasons. From the [release announcement](https://logback.qos.ch/news.html):

> Removed Groovy configuration support. As logging is so pervasive and configuration with Groovy is probably too powerful, this feature is unlikely to be reinstated for security reasons.

This removal, along with some other changes, was done in response to [CVE-2021-42550](https://cve.report/CVE-2021-42550).

Answer (score 0):

As mentionend in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71554807/9066300 downgrading to logback 1.2.7 may be an workaround if you can mitigate the risk of the CVE mentioned in the accepted answer.